# CV function in RidgeCV

Tags: scikit-learn, regression

I am working with the Ridge regression function in sci-kit learn.

There is a cross validation function RidgeCV. The basic (example) settings are:

```
RidgeCV(alphas=[0.1, 1.0, 10.0], cv=None, fit_intercept=True, scoring=None,
    normalize=False,store_cv_values=True)
```

Lets say I wanted to do a 10 fold CV. Am I setting it with the "cv= " argument? Every RidgeCV I look at has cv set to cv=None.

1) Not even sure this is the right place to set a 10 fold.

2) Can't find in the documentation the other CV= parameters values besides "None".

Thanks

Comment: for 2): [fixed in master](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/6e7b11e0ffe835f6d39a23d7f3ed35af131220eb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `cv=None`, then `RidgeCV` will perform leave-one-out cross-validation using the "Generalized cross validation" formula, an analytic formula that will provide you with the leave-one-out errors for the computational cost of one ridge regression.

If you want to use other cross validation schemes, you can: Just import them from `sklearn.cross_validation`. For example

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, ShuffleSplit

cv1 = KFold(n_samples, k=10)
cv2 = ShuffleSplit(n_samples, test_size=.2, n_iter=20)
```

You can then pass these iterators as `cv=...`. If you set `cv` to a number, eg `cv=5`, then it will default to `KFold(n_samples, k=5)` cross validation.